# Linux discover disks and partitions

Tags: linux, shell, disk, partition

I am looking for a script to discover disk usage/total size, its partition info. I understand commands like 'df', 'fdisk', 'blkid' will produce such information, and a lot of more than I need.  So I am wondering whether there is a script to cut info to just show something like:
Disk=/dev/sdb3; total=3000 GB; used=30%; system=Linux; TYPE = "ext3"
...
...

And also need such info for both mounted and unmounted disks.

I did some search in stackoverflow, but didn't find such script although I am pretty such experts here know this is an easy question. well, I am not a linux person... that is something I need to learn. :-)

thanks

nidm

Comment: You should learn more about [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see limited output from, say `df`, you could try using `grep`:

```
df -h | grep /dev/sd
```

This will show only the lines from `df` that match "/dev/sd", thus showing your mounted disks.